# MySQL Database & PHP - Match row with files and append extension

Tags: php, mysql, search, replace

i've got the following problem:

I've taken over a MS-SQL Database from my superior which has been developed by him. Sadly the database is in really bad shape for development.

The Database has already been "converted" to MySQL by me and the data imported. Now the problem is, theres a table "hotels" which had got rows named "image1, image2, image3" etc up to image24. I removed them from the table and created a new table called hotel_images where the images are assigned to a hotel. Now to describe my problem :

The imported data contained strings for each image such as "007593-20110809-145433-01" but the extension was missing. All the images were placed in the same directory (there are about 4000) and only the string has been saved.

I already did a workaround function myself when pulling the data into the website where i check file_exists and then return the different extensions (.BMP, .GIF, JPG etc) but i don't like this solution.

Is there any possiblity for me to check all strings available in a single table with the image folder and add the proper extension to the table if the string matches? It must be something like

```
SELECT image from hotel_images (search for value in /images/) IF MATCH ALTER TABLE hotel_images set image = this + .extension
```

I would appreciate any advice!

Edit: it just came to my attention that i could do a dir listing to a text-file from the folder and then match it against every string in the table and if match replace it - is that a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to SELECT all rows (without extension)

Then, in PHP, foreach on all images to find if they're existing in the folder, take their extensions

Then UPDATE row with the existing filename, adding the extension...

With an example :

```
$images_query = mysql_query("SELECT id, image_name from hotel_images");

while($image = mysql_fetch_array($images_query)){
  if(file_exists($image["image_name"])){
    //Get extension
    $ext = "...";

    //Then update row with new name
    mysql_query("UPDATE hotel_images SET image_name = '" . $image["image_name"] . $ext ."' WHERE id = " . $image["id"]);

  }

}
```

Are you searching for something like that ?

It's not tested script, did it directly in the SO textarea ;)

Comment: Of course .... why the hell haven't i've been thinking of that. Thank you for the hint ;)